# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'File' for h5py

Tags: python, h5py

So here is the beginning of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import h5py
f = h5py.File("/data/vera/run-2/hdfaa.001","r")
```

When I run it, it works well in the home directory. But when I run this in the directories inside the home directory, there is the error printed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "h5py.py", line 3, in <module>
import h5py
File "/.../h5py.py", line 5, in <module>
f = h5py.File("/...","r")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'File'
```

When I use IPython of python interpreter, it can import the library and have the attribute h5py.File. But once I have the script interpreted, the interpreter cannot import the h5py library anymore. After I have deleted the file, it works fine again.

I have used the interpreter to check my script and there shouldn't be  any problem with the scripting.

Since I am quite new to python, so I have no idea where goes wrong.

Comment: Change the name of your `h5py.py` file.  It is hiding the `h5py` that you want to import.

Comment: Let me add, for future use, that there can be no 'h5py.py' in the folder. So if you created one earlier, it is still covering you working file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Uninstall h5py : `pip uninstall h5py`
- Install h5py : `pip install h5py`

Actually I checked the h5py package that was already present, and it seemed corrupted to me. So I did the obvious, and voila, it worked!

Comment: conda installtion worked for me. 
`$ conda install h5py`

Comment: This answer could be improved with more details. That said, it worked for me so I'll give it a vote.